# python module import error - python-mode [VIM]

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, python-mode

I am trying to import a module from another directory and run the script using `python-mode`. I am encountering, module not found error, but the module is present in the location and my `sys.path` shows the module path has been added successfully. I am having hard time troubleshooting/fixing. Could some one shed some light on this?

```
import numpy as np
import sys
sys.path.append('./extnsn/')
from extnsn import FX
```

The error stack is:

> Feat/mFeat/feat_Xt_v2.py|7 error| in  from
>   extnsn import FX ImportError: No module named 'extnsn'

My directory structure is:

```
Feat
    |
    |--mFeat
    |
    |--feat_Xt_v2.py
    |
    |--extnsn
            |
            |--__init__.py
            |--FX.py
```

The `extnsn` directory has a `__init__.py` with the following:

```
from extnsn import FX
```

`FX.py` is the module name, for information.

`sys.path` contains the appended path as `./extnsn/` as the last entry in the list.

What makes me conclude this is not path issue is that, the program runs fine, if executed from `atom` with `script` plugin.

Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

This doesn't seem to be an issue with just `python-mode`, rather the way how `vim` invoke the python interpretor and execute the buffer. I tried with the following command without `python-mode` and the issue is the same.

Answer (score 2):

To import a module or a package you have to add to `sys.path` its parent directory. In your case if you've added `./extnsn/` to `sys.path` you cannot import `extnsn` (it cannot be found in `sys.path`) but you can import `FX` directly:

```
import FX
```

But as `FX` seems to be a module in a package `extnsn` you better add to `sys.path` the parent directory of `extnsn`, i.e. `Feat`:

```
sys.path.append('../Feat')
from extnsn import FX
```